# Square of antisymmetric matrix is symmetric and negative definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that if $M$ is antisymmetric, then $M^2$ is
>
> 1. symmetric, and
> 2. negative definite.

I have no idea where to begin. I tried to diagonalise the matrix and attempt something with $D^2 = S^T M^2 S$, but I don’t really know what I can do with this information, especially since I don’t have information about the eigenvalues of $M$. Could someone help me proceed from here? Thanks!

Comment: The first one should not be that difficult. Just play around with the definition of an anti-symmetric / symmetric matrix and the properties of transpose.

Comment: Regarding the second one, the eigenvalues of a real skew-symmetric matrix are all imaginary. Taking this as a fact and the fact that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $M^2$, we can prove the second statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(M^2)^T=(M^T)^2=(-M)^2=M^2$$
hence $M^2$ is symmetric

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$(x,M^2x)=x^TM^2x=x^T(-M^T)Mx=-x^TM^TMx=-\|Mx\|_2^2 \le0$$
hence $M^2$ is negative semidefinite.

You need additional conditions to prove that $M^2$ is negative definite. As stated, $M$ could, for example, be the null matrix.

Comment: Hi there, what kind of constraints should I be looking to place on M for negative definite M? Should I be looking more at the determinant?

Comment: @user107224 $det(M^2)=det(M)^2$ hence $M$ is definite if and only if $det(M) \ne 0$